# Stop multiple timers running in background in android

Tags: android, multithreading

I have started some timers at different times in an activity. Each timer has its own expiry. But I want to stop all timers that are running in the background when a particular condition occurs.

How can I stop multiple timers running in the background in Android?

Comment: How do you start the timers? Have references to them and call https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#cancel()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can easy Cancel the timer. 
check below code.

```
private static Timer abc_Timer;
abc_Timer=new Timer();
/*`your logic`*/
abc_Timer.cancel(); //cancel method will cancel your timer
//After use of cancel method use
abc_timer.purge(); //this method will remove all cancelled timer.
```